# Upload new logo image for my JSF App with a dynamic way

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I need your help on how to upload new logo image to my jsf app by clicking on button `Upload` so that the old logo should be overwritten by the new one.
( is there an idea or suggestion on how to handle that ? )

to explain more: 
In my current version I have a static logo implemented in the jsf part( the logo.png is stored under ressources/gfx folder not in the database) :

```
<h:panelGrid>

        <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['gfx:logo.png']}" />

</h:panelGrid>
```

My aim is to implement it with a dynamic way.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Uploading is totally independent of showing. There are multiple Q/A in stackoverflow about uploading files (an image IS a file) in jsf

Comment: And for displaying dynamic images there are multiple Q/A too.

Comment: Since the logo is editable by the end user, you need to read it from an external location (resources are read from your deployment, so not an option here). You must place user uploaded files somewhere outside your deployment directory (DB or file directory)

Comment: @XtremeBiker thank you for the information